# Error in installing "sudo pip install -V protobuf==3.0.0a2"

Tags: software-installation, python

When I want to install protobuf, I typed the command: `pip install -V protobuf==3.0.0a2`, then I received the following results:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==8.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2472, in load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2186, in load
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from pip.commands import get_summaries, get_similar_commands
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip.commands.freeze import FreezeCommand
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/freeze.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip.operations.freeze import freeze
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/operations/freeze.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import RequirementParseError
 ImportError: cannot import name RequirementParseError
```

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

You did something wrong.

1. remove `pip` from */usr/local/bin*
2. install `pip` from official repository (`sudo apt-get install python-pip`)
3. then install protobuf with `sudo pip install -V protobuf==3.0.0a2`

After these actions I got *protobuf 3.0.0a2* installed to */usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages*.

Please remember the rule: if you need some software, try to [find its package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/) and then install with apt-get. It is not Windows with its EXE, MSI and MSP. Installing software from third-party packages or compiled from the source code will result in a littering of the system and make it more difficult to administer and use.